# change chart data range when dynamic data range changes?

Tags: excel, charts, range, excel-2010, vba

I have created a dynamic name range in my worksheet, which is called 'grafiekrange' (chartrange in dutch). I Created a chart and where you select the chart data range, I typed: 
`='blad1'!grafiekrange` because blad1 is the worksheet name where the name range is located.

I press ok and the chart is connected to the *range* of cells the name refers to at that particular moment. When the range from the name range expands, the data range for the chart is still the same.
So when I connect the chart to the *name* range, excel somehow converts the name range to a hard coded range of cells; e.g. `$A$1:$H$10` instead of `'blad1'!grafiekrange`.

I found some vba code which is some sort of workaround, but this workaround deletes the chart and creates a new one, on every single change in the worksheet.

this is the code for the *worksheet*:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
With ActiveSheet
.ChartObjects.Delete
End With
Call CreateChart
End Sub
```

this is the code in the *module*:

```
Option Explicit
'=========================================================================
Sub CreateChart()
   Dim objChart As ChartObject
   Dim myChtRange As Range
   Dim myDataRange As Range
   With ActiveSheet
    ' What range should chart cover

    Set myChtRange = Range("chtArea")   'Range("G2:Q30")
    ' What range contains data for chart


    Set myDataRange = Range("grafiekrange")


    ' Cover chart range with chart
    Set objChart = .ChartObjects.Add( _
        Left:=myChtRange.Left, Top:=myChtRange.Top, _
        Width:=myChtRange.Width, Height:=myChtRange.Height)
    ' Put all the right stuff in the chart
    With objChart.Chart
      .ChartArea.AutoScaleFont = False
      .ChartType = xlLine
      .SetSourceData Source:=myDataRange, PlotBy:=xlRows
           .HasTitle = True
           .ChartTitle.Characters.Text = "YTD Afzetontwikkeling (cumulatief) bij AS Watson (KV+TP)"
      .ChartTitle.Font.Bold = True
      .ChartTitle.Font.Size = 12
      With .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary)
        .HasTitle = False
      End With
    End With
   End With
  End Sub
  '=========================================================================
```

Creating a new chart on every single change is not exactly what I wanted, but if it does what I want, it doesn't matter it works like this.
However, I would like to have 2 series with certain formatting. The first 2 series should have a dash line. 
I used the macro recorder to see how this works and tried to implement this in the code above. But I did not succeed in have a working code.

this is the code the macro recorder returns:

```
Sub Macro3()
'
' Macro3 Macro
'

'
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Grafiek 29").Activate
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MajorGridlines.Select
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Select
With Selection.Format.Line
  .Visible = msoTrue
  .DashStyle = msoLineDash
End With
End Sub
```

My question is: 
can you either help me implement the series formatting in the code above, or provide me a code which just updates the data range on every single change (to me, that sounds more efficiently but I do not know how to do so).
many thanks in advance.

I tried something myself but that does not the chart data and somehow, now returns an error where I first did not:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal myrange As Range)

Set myrange = grafiekrange

  With ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Grafiek 35")

    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:="myrange" 

  End With

End Sub
```

Comment: I don't believe there is VBA necessary for this. http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/microsoft-office/two-ways-to-build-dynamic-charts-in-excel/

Comment: ah. I understand the dynamic range method. Although I hoped I just could enter 1 dynamic range for the entire chart. But Ok, I have to create a dyname range for each individual series and axis.

Comment: It helps for expanding the data range for the individual series. But not for having new series added. It is a pity that the option to just connect the chart data to a dynamic named range is not available.

Comment: Why not use "The table method"?

Comment: I tried. But the table method, converts all my data in to plain tekst. And I will lose my formula's. And my data is 100% formula's, which will change when new periods of data are available in the source sheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what I changed but I have a working method. 
I added this code in a module:

```
Option Explicit
'=========================================================================
Sub CreateChart()
Dim objChart As ChartObject
Dim myChtRange As range
Dim myDataRange As range
With ActiveSheet
' What range should chart cover

    Set myChtRange = range("chtArea")   'Range("G2:Q30")
' What range contains data for chart


Set myDataRange = range("grafiekrange")


' Cover chart range with chart
Set objChart = .ChartObjects.Add( _
    Left:=myChtRange.Left, Top:=myChtRange.Top, _
    Width:=myChtRange.Width, Height:=myChtRange.Height)
' Put all the right stuff in the chart
With objChart.Chart
    .ChartArea.AutoScaleFont = False
    .ChartType = xlLine
   .SetSourceData Source:=myDataRange, PlotBy:=xlRows
           .HasTitle = True
           .ChartTitle.Characters.Text = "YTD Afzetontwikkeling (cumulatief) bij AS Watson (KV+TP)"
    .ChartTitle.Font.Bold = True
    .ChartTitle.Font.Size = 12
    With .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary)
        .HasTitle = False
    End With
End With
End With
End Sub
'==========
```

and then in worksheet I have this sub:

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal myrange As range)
Dim grafiekrange As range

Set myrange = grafiekrange

With ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Grafiek 3").Activate

ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=range("grafiekrange")

End With

End Sub
```

And in the worksheet I have a few named ranges of which the grafiekrange is used now. this named range has this formula:

`=VERSCHUIVING(Blad4!$A$1;0;0;AANTALARG(Blad4!$A:$A)+1;AANTAL.ALS(Blad4!$1:$1;"YTD*")+1)`

where:

VERSCHUIVING = OFFSET()

AANTAL.ALS = COUNTIF

AANTALARG = COUNTA

And Now it works.

Now I only have to find a solution for positioning the chart on every change (which is included already in the code above)

Answer (score 0):

I can't believe, that the Insert Table kills the formulas, but anyway.

If the `='blad1'!grafiekrange` gets the right Chart data, then put the following macro into a module:

```
Sub setSelectedChartSourceData()
 Dim oChart As Chart

 On Error Resume Next 'If Selection is not the CharArea, then next line throws error.

 Set oChart = Selection.Parent
 oChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("blad1!grafiekrange")

 On Error GoTo 0 'Set Error handling to default.

End Sub
```

You can assign a keyboard shortcut to the macro. [Ctrl]+[Shift]+[D] for ex.

Now, if the chart data and the named range data has changed, select the Chart and press [Ctrl]+[Shift]+[D] or run the macro setSelectedChartSourceData in another way.

Greetings

Axel

Comment: sorry. maybe I might not have read the warning message properly. the exact warning message is: "formulas in the rowname will be deleted and converted to static text." I have now converted the range to a table and then tried to see what happens. I connected the chart to the table and made some selections. Nothing happens. When I checked again for the Chart date range, I saw there was a static range mentioned instead of the table.

Comment: Sorry, I can't reproduce this behavior. My Excel is version 2007. Neither the message comes up if I use Insert Table with a filled range nor the formulas or formats goes away. Only the backgrounds of the cells changes. And if I create a chart from the table data - of course it has to be a chart of the whole table data - and then insert data in new rows or columns, the chart also inserts values or series.

Comment: I have tried several times several options, but none of them work. Every time, the range is converted in a "normal" range (R1K1 style). instead of the named range or the tabel range. I converted my range to a table using 'insert table' and then entered the named range. When I already had the table, I changed the table size with 'change table size' and there I pasted the dynamic range formula. I was hoping then the table would expand itself and the chart would use the whole table area. But again, the range is converted to a normal range and so is the chart range. What is happening here?

Comment: one more thing: when I convert my range to a table, my x-axis lables are converted to plain tekst (these also are formula based and my formula's are gone)